# Retrofit request with multiple parameters in kotlin not working correct

Tags: android, kotlin

**My code in the Api interface:**

```
 interface APIServiceUpdateTeam {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("/api/v1/updateTeam/{Id}/")
    suspend fun updateTeam(@Path("Id")teamId: String,
                           @Header("Authorization") token: String,
                           @FieldMap params: 
            HashMap<String?,ArrayList<*>>): Response<ResponseBody>,
    
   }
```

**//my code the request call**

```
val params = HashMap<String?, ArrayList<*>>()
params.put("members",teamMemberListToUpdate)
params.put("name",teamIdToAdd)
params.put("password", passwordTeamAdd)


val response =
    service.updateTeam(teamIdToAdd.toString(),"Token ${token}", params)
```

//So the post/put request is 2 times a string (name and password) and 1 Array of integers, int his example members. In my example here the HashMap is an array of integers so the name and password are not accepted.

Comment: did you tested api with your params ?

Comment: yes, iam coming from swift and the api is working fine. The problem is the combination in the request of an Array(members) and String(name and password).

Comment: "Token ${token}" , are you sure authorization starts with "Token" ?

Comment: yep, thats not the problem. Problem is that i have 3 parameters, 1 array and 2 strings. What i dont know is how to pass 3 different sort of parameters in the request (Array and string)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to specify value type as `Any` type

```
val params = HashMap<String?, Any>()
params.put("members",teamMemberListToUpdate)
params.put("name",teamIdToAdd)
params.put("password", passwordTeamAdd)
```

This way you can put different types into map

Comment: This isnt working i think because the params name and password is not a HashMap, just String. The param Members is an Array of Int

Comment: The `params` variable is a `HashMap`. Do you need the value of the HashMap to be a HashMap also?

Comment: The api wants a list as input voor de param Members (its django rest framework)

Comment: Can you post the api specification?

Comment: api want a name, a password and the members. Name is a string, password is a string, and members is an array of members. Iam coming from swift, where the exact same request is working. There i use alamofire.
In alamofire i can juist specify the parameters and its type.

Comment: So if we didnt use the FieldMap it would look smth like this?

`interface APIServiceUpdateTeam {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @PUT("/api/v1/updateTeam/{Id}/")
        suspend fun updateTeam(
            @Path("Id") teamId: String,
            @Header("Authorization") token: String,
            @Field("name") name: String,
            @Field("password") password: String,
            @Field("members") members: List<Int>
        ): ResponseBody
    }`

Comment: Also i think the int array is converted to String anyway by Retrofit so you can just use `HashMap<String, String>` and convert `teamMemberListToUpdate.toString()`

Comment: This did the job!!. The @Field annotation, than i can specify the type per parameter. Great. tx.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't change the password like that you need to make it separatly from the PUT.
you can make your put like this :

```
 @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
    @PUT("/api/v1/updateTeam/{id}")
    suspend fun modify(
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
        @Path("id") id: String,
        @Body team: Team,
    ): Response<ResponseBody>
```

or

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("/api/v1/updateTeam/{id}")
  suspend fun modify(
      @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
      @Path("id") id: String,
      @Field("membres") member: List<Any>,
      @Field("name") name: String,
  ): Response<ResponseBody>
```